# Why multithreaded memory allocate/deallocate intensive application does not scale with number of threads?

Tags: json, multithreading, delphi, dwscript

**Notice:**

Original post title

> Why multithreaded JSON parser from DWScript does not scale with number of threads?

was changed because this problem is *not related to processing JSON data with DWScript*. 
The problem is in default memory manager in Delphi XE2 to XE7 ( tested were XE2 and trial XE7 ), but problem appeared first in such type of application.

---

I have multithreaded Win32/Win64 vcl application which process JSON data in Delphi XE2.

Each thread parses JSON data using `TdwsJSONValue.ParseString(sJSON)` from DWScript, reads values using DWScript methods and stores result as records.

For testing purposes I process same JSON data in each thread.

Single thead run takes `N` seconds within thread to process data. Increasing number of threads to `M` lineary (approx. `M * N`) increases time within single thread necessary to process same data.

In result there is no speed improvment. Other parts of this applications ( JSON data delivery, storing results in target environment ) - scale as expected.

What could be a reason ?  Any ideas appreciated.

Supplemental information:

1. Tested on Win7/32 and Win7/64, Win8/64 from 2-core to 12-core (w/w-out HT) systems
2. DWScript was choosen as fastest available (tested a bunch, among them: Superobject, build-in Delphi). SO behaves similar as JSON unit from DWS.
3. Below is complete console app illustrating the problem. To run it we need sample json data available here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4iuv87ytpcdugk6/json1.zip?dl=0 This file contains data `json1.dat` for first thread. For threads up to 16 just copy json1.dat to json2.dat...json16.dat.

   Program and data shoule be in the same folder. To run: convert.exe N, where N is number of threads.

   Program writes time of execution in msecs to stout - spent in thread, time of parsing data and time of releasing (Destroy) TdwsJSONValue object.
   Statement `_dwsjvData.Destroy;` does not scale.

---

```
program Convert;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Diagnostics,
  System.Classes,
  dwsJSON in 'dwsJSON.pas',
  dwsStrings in 'dwsStrings.pas',
  dwsUtils in 'dwsUtils.pas',
  dwsXPlatform in 'dwsXPlatform.pas';

type

  TWorkerThread = class (TThread)
  private
    _iUid:  Integer;
    _swWatch:  TStopwatch;
    _lRunning:  Boolean;

    _sFileJSonData:  String;
    _fJsonData:  TextFile;

  protected
    constructor Create (AUid: Integer);
    procedure Execute; override;

  published
    property Running: Boolean read _lRunning;

  end;

  TConverter = class (TObject)
  private
    _swWatch0, _swWatch1, _swWatch2:  TStopwatch;

    _dwsjvData:  TdwsJSONValue;

  protected
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    function Calculate (AUid: Integer; AJSonData: String; var AParse, ADestroy: Integer): Integer;
  end;

const
  MAX_THREADS = 16;

var
  iHowMany:  Integer;
  athWorker:  array [1..MAX_THREADS] of Pointer;
  aiElapsed:  array [1..MAX_THREADS] of Integer;
  aiElapsedParse:  array [1..MAX_THREADS] of Integer;
  aiElapsedDestroy:  array [1..MAX_THREADS] of Integer;
  aiFares:  array [1..MAX_THREADS] of Integer;
  swWatchT, swWatchP:  TStopwatch;


constructor TWorkerThread.Create (AUid: Integer);
begin
  inherited Create (True);

  _iUid := AUid;
  _swWatch := TStopwatch.Create;
  _sFileJSonData := ExtractFilePath (ParamStr (0)) + 'json' + Trim (IntToStr (_iUid)) + '.dat';

  _lRunning := False;

  Suspended := False;
end;

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
var
  j:  Integer;
  sLine:  String;
  slLines:  TStringList;

  oS:  TConverter;
begin
  _lRunning := True;

  oS := TConverter.Create;

  slLines := TStringList.Create;
  System.AssignFile (_fJsonData, _sFileJSonData);
  System.Reset (_fJsonData);
  j := 0;
  repeat
    System.Readln (_fJsonData, sLine);
    slLines.Add (sLine);
    Inc (j);
  until (j = 50);
//  until (System.Eof (_fJsonData));
  System.Close (_fJsonData);

  Sleep (1000);

  _swWatch.Reset;
  _swWatch.Start;

  aiFares [_iUid] := 0;
  aiElapsedParse [_iUid] := 0;
  aiElapsedDestroy [_iUid] := 0;
  for j := 1 to slLines.Count do
    aiFares [_iUid] := aiFares [_iUid] + oS.Calculate (_iUid, slLines.Strings [j - 1], aiElapsedParse [_iUid], aiElapsedDestroy [_iUid]);

  _swWatch.Stop;

  slLines.Free;
  os.Destroy;

  aiElapsed [_iUid] := _swWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

  _lRunning := False;
end;

constructor TConverter.Create;
begin
  inherited Create;

  _swWatch0 := TStopwatch.Create;
  _swWatch1 := TStopwatch.Create;
  _swWatch2 := TStopwatch.Create;
end;

destructor TConverter.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

function TConverter.Calculate (AUid: Integer; AJSonData: String; var AParse, ADestroy: Integer): Integer;
var
  jFare, jTotalFares, iElapsedParse, iElapsedDestroy, iElapsedTotal:  Integer;
begin
  _swWatch0.Reset;
  _swWatch0.Start;

  _swWatch1.Reset;
  _swWatch1.Start;
  _dwsjvData := TdwsJSONValue.ParseString (AJSonData);
  _swWatch1.Stop;
  iElapsedParse := _swWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds;

  if (_dwsjvData.ValueType = jvtArray) then
  begin
    _swWatch2.Reset;
    _swWatch2.Start;

    jTotalFares := _dwsjvData.ElementCount;
    for jFare := 0 to (jTotalFares - 1) do
      if (_dwsjvData.Elements [jFare].ValueType = jvtObject) then
      begin

        _swWatch1.Reset;
        _swWatch1.Start;

        _swWatch1.Stop;
      end;
  end;

  _swWatch1.Reset;
  _swWatch1.Start;
  _dwsjvData.Destroy;
  _swWatch1.Stop;
  iElapsedDestroy := _swWatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds;

  _swWatch0.Stop;
  iElapsedTotal := _swWatch0.ElapsedMilliseconds;

  Inc (AParse, iElapsedParse);
  Inc (ADestroy, iElapsedDestroy);

  result := jTotalFares;
end;

procedure MultithreadStart;
var
  j:  Integer;
begin
  for j := 1 to iHowMany do
    if (athWorker [j] = nil) then
    begin
      athWorker [j] := TWorkerThread.Create (j);

      TWorkerThread (athWorker [j]).FreeOnTerminate := False;
      TWorkerThread (athWorker [j]).Priority := tpNormal;
    end;
end;

procedure MultithreadStop;
var
  j:  Integer;
begin
  for j := 1 to MAX_THREADS do
    if (athWorker [j] <> nil) then
    begin
      TWorkerThread (athWorker [j]).Terminate;
      TWorkerThread (athWorker [j]).WaitFor;

      TWorkerThread (athWorker [j]).Free;
      athWorker [j] := nil;
    end;
end;

procedure Prologue;
var
  j:  Integer;
begin
  iHowMany := StrToInt (ParamStr (1));

  for j := 1 to MAX_THREADS do
    athWorker [j] := nil;

  swWatchT := TStopwatch.Create;
  swWatchT.Reset;

  swWatchP := TStopwatch.Create;
  swWatchP.Reset;
end;

procedure RunConvert;

  function __IsRunning: Boolean;
  var
    j:  Integer;
  begin
    result := False;
    for j := 1 to MAX_THREADS do
      result := result or ((athWorker [j] <> nil) and TWorkerThread (athWorker [j]).Running);
  end;

begin

  swWatchT.Start;

  MultithreadStart;

  Sleep (1000);
  while (__isRunning) do
    Sleep (500);

  MultithreadStop;

  swWatchT.Stop;
  Writeln (#13#10, 'Total time:', swWatchT.ElapsedMilliseconds);
end;

procedure Epilogue;
var
  j:  Integer;
begin
  for j := 1 to iHowMany do
    Writeln ( #13#10, 'Thread # ', j, '  tot.time:', aiElapsed [j], '  fares:', aiFares [j], '  tot.parse:', aiElapsedParse [j], '  tot.destroy:', aiElapsedDestroy [j]);

  Readln;
end;

begin
  try
    Prologue;
    RunConvert;
    Epilogue;

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln (E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Without code, without description of the input process (source), and without your OS and CPU architecture? This is not a guessing game!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you use DWScript for this? Is the data used by more the application uses DWScript for?

Comment: It's clearly not really running on multiple threads. Use the debugger to discover why. While your code is running, pause it and look at the stack traces of all your threads. That will show you which ones are active and which are blocked waiting for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is exchange default Delphi XE2 or XE7 memory manager with Intel® Threading Building Blocks memory manager. In example application it scales ca. lineary with number of threads up to 16 when app is 64 bits.

*`update: with assumption that number of threads running is less than number of cores`*

This was tested on machines from 2cores/4ht to 12cores/24ht running KVM virtualized Windows 7 with 124GB RAM

Interesting thing is virtualizing Win 7. memory allocation and deallocation is from 2 x faster as in native Win 7.

Conclusion: if you do a lot of memory allocation / deallocation operations of 10kB-10MB blocks in threads of multithreaded ( more than 4-8 threads) application - use only memory manager from Intel.

@André: thanks for tip pointing me to right direction!

Here is unit with TBB memory manager taken for tests, it has to appear as 1st on unit list in main project file .dpr

```
unit TBBMem;

interface

function  ScalableGetMem  (ASize: NativeInt): Pointer; cdecl; external 'tbbmalloc' name 'scalable_malloc';
procedure ScalableFreeMem (APtr: Pointer); cdecl; external 'tbbmalloc' name 'scalable_free';
function  ScalableReAlloc (APtr: Pointer; Size: NativeInt): Pointer; cdecl; external 'tbbmalloc' name 'scalable_realloc';

implementation

Function TBBGetMem (ASize: Integer): Pointer;
begin
  result := ScalableGetMem (ASize);
end;

Function TBBFreeMem (APtr: Pointer): Integer;
begin
  ScalableFreeMem (APtr);
  result := 0;
end;

Function TBBReAllocMem (APtr: Pointer; ASize: Integer): Pointer;
begin
  result := ScalableRealloc (APtr, ASize);
end;

const
  TBBMemoryManager:  TMemoryManager = ( GetMem: TBBGetmem;
                                        FreeMem: TBBFreeMem;
                                        ReAllocMem:  TBBReAllocMem; );
var
  oldMemoryManager:  TMemoryManager;

initialization
  GetMemoryManager (oldMemoryManager);
  SetMemoryManager (TBBMemoryManager);

finalization
  SetMemoryManager (oldMemoryManager);

end.
```

Comment: which version of TBB did you use? Can you put the whole application including TBB on dropbox?

Comment: I did a (re)test of the FastCode MM Challenge, and the results were not that good for TBB (also out of memory exception in block downsize test) 
Average Speed Performance: (Scaled so that the winner = 100%)
  D2010Mem    :   70,4
  TCmalloc    :   89,1
  ScaleMem2   :  100,0
  TBBMem      :   77,8

Average Memory Performance: (Scaled so that the winner = 100%)
  D2010Mem    :  100,0
  TCmalloc    :   29,6
  ScaleMem2   :   75,6
  TBBMem      :   38,4

Comment: I took tbbmalloc.dll version 4.3.2014.723, I am not sure if I can put this on dropbox, but site for download is https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/, full code is in my answer

Comment: There is happy end  - finally satisfied solution was found. Instead of one application running multiple ( 8 - 30 ) alloc/dealloc memory intensive threads I did simplified application with one alloc/dealloc memory intensive thread and it is running parallel in 8-32 copies. In this case scaling is the best, and application itself is not complicated

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried my scaleable memory manager? Because Delphi (with fastmm internally) does not scale well with strings and other memory related stuff:
https://scalemm.googlecode.com/files/ScaleMM_v2_4_1.zip

And you could also try both profiler modes of my profiler to see which part is the bottleneck:
https://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/

Comment: Not yet, but thank you for a tip. I will do. At the moment I am checking 
Threading Building Blocks from Intel.

Comment: I tested with ScaleMM. Results are better - 2 x faster (average speed improvement for 8-16 simultaneous hreads).dwsJSONValue.Destroy is pretty fast

Comment: but dwsJSONValue.Parser slowed down noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

I did a (re)test of the FastCode MM Challenge, and the results were not that good for TBB (also out of memory exception in block downsize test).

In short: ScaleMM2 and Google TCmalloc are the fastest in this complex test, Fastmm and ScaleMM2 use the least memory.

```
Average Speed Performance: (Scaled so that the winner = 100%)
  XE6         :   70,4
  TCmalloc    :   89,1
  ScaleMem2   :  100,0
  TBBMem      :   77,8

Average Memory Performance: (Scaled so that the winner = 100%)
  XE6         :  100,0
  TCmalloc    :   29,6
  ScaleMem2   :   75,6
  TBBMem      :   38,4
```

FastCode Challenge: https://code.google.com/p/scalemm/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FChallenge 
TBB 4.3: https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/download

Comment: I needed good multithreading scaling in application to process multi terabytes json data, that means a lot of get/release mem. In tests Intel's TBB was best scaling. I did not test TCmalloc yet, but will do.

Comment: @YpsArthur are you sure? I tested your convert application and SMM2 used less memory and was faster (I added for i := 0 to 50 in TWorkerThread.Execute) => SMM2, 4 threads = 8.5s, 65mb active, 22mb idle; TBBv4.3 = 9s, 75mb active, 73mb(!) idle. But TBB seems quite good too :)

Comment: Yes, TBB was best solution for 16 threads because even if not fastest, it offered predictable stable scaling in my production environment. Memory consumption is not most important factor, speed (even if not fastest, but fast enough) should be stable with threads increase. When necessary and I have time I can deliver some screenshots with output from test program for different memory managers.

Comment: @YpsArthur In my test TBB 4.4 is like 6x slower than ScaleMM2 and FastMM4 in multithreaded concat test.