# multi-cored, multi-threaded speedup: reading through CSVs using TMemoryStream

Tags: multithreading, delphi, csv, memorystream

I'm writing parallel code to enumerate over a large set of CSV files, each full of Historical Stock Data (over 6500 Symbols) and calculate whether each stock has reached its all-time high.

I've implemented a Thread Pool and TThread descendant class to split up the list of symbols equally among Threads, which threads are then allocated to SEPARATE cores of my i7 machine.  I setup the threads to each have a copy of all the data they need when they are created before unsuspending them, so there's no locking needed or going on while the threads are processing.  Once all the threads have finished, I aggregate the result data of each thread into the main program.

I've currently tested my code using several of the multi-threaded memory managers mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072269/need-multi-threading-memory-manager/6076407#6076407.  So far, SapMM seems to be the most efficient one without causing access violations.

The problem is that adding more threads is not proportionately speeding up the time it takes to finish calculating all the highs.  Using 2 "core-d" threads doesn't cut the running time by quite 1/2, but 3 doesn't fully cut to 1/3, and 4 doesn't cut near to 1/4.

Number of Threads
1,
2,
3,
4

Projected Speedup Time (mm:ss)
6:37,
3:17 1/2,
2:12 1/3,
1:39 1/4

Actual Time (mm:ss)
6:37,
4:07,
3:05,
2:51

I've come to a point where I need some additional insight to get the full speedup of this operation.  I need to get to the bottom of why the multicore speedup is trailing off, rather than just "dabble around the edges of the problem."  So, what's causing this code to stop getting proportionate gains, and what do I need to do to achieve those gains?  In short, is there some other approach to speed up the parsing I'm doing, e.g. rather than to use TMemoryStream?

The code I'm using is below.

I'm using Delphi XE4 Enterprise.

In each thread I loop through each symbol and:

1. Use TMemoryStream.LoadFromFile to load the historical data of the symbol.
2. Use a function I wrote to retrieve the highest high of the symbol data directly from the TMemoryStream.

(1) is tested and doesn't take any time (less than 1 second total time taken to load all 6500, one at a time, into memory).  The procedure I use in (2) is what's taking all the time, and is listed below:

```
unit uTest;

implementation

uses
  SysUtils, Math, Classes;

type
  TDayIndexData = record
      Date: TDate;
      Open, High, Low, Close, AdjClose,
      Volume: extended;
    end;

type
  TTimeUnit = (tuDay, tuWeek, tuMonth, tuYear);

  TTimePeriod = record
    Length: integer;
    TimeUnit: TTimeUnit;
  end;

//#NO CHANGE
const
  AllDataPeriodStr = 'All Data';

type
  TRatePeriod = record
    PeriodStr: string;
    TimePeriod: TTimePeriod;
  end;

type
  TFieldType = (ftDate, ftOpen, ftHigh, ftLow, ftClose, ftVolume, ftAdjClose);

const CSV_DELIM_CHARSET = [#0..#31, ',',#127];

type
  TShallowEquityNewHighInfoRetrievalResults = record
    Success: boolean;
    High: extended;
  end;

function ShallowEquityNewHighInfoRetrieval(
  AStream: TStream;
  ARatePeriod: TRatePeriod;
  AGetNormalData: boolean = False): TShallowEquityNewHighInfoRetrievalResults;

var
  vStreamSize: int64;

  function EOF: boolean;
  begin
    Result := AStream.Position >= vStreamSize;//AStream.Size;
  end;

  procedure GotoEOF;
  begin
    AStream.Seek(0, soFromEnd);
  end;

//#OPTIMIZE
//var
  //vBuffer: FileString;

  type
    FileChar = AnsiChar;
    FileString = AnsiString;

  const
    ResultCharSize = SizeOf(FileChar);

  var
    MRReadChar: FileChar;

  procedure ReadNextChar;
  begin
    if not EOF then
      AStream.Read(MRReadChar, SizeOf(MRReadChar)) else
        raise EInvalidOperation.Create('Unexpected end of file found');
  end;

  var
    vPossDelimChars: boolean;

  procedure SkipExistingDelimChars;
  begin
    //*INTENTION: prevents redundant SkipDelimChars calls, which is destructive
    if not vPossDelimChars then Exit;

    //not requiring DelimChars

    if EOF then Exit;

    repeat
      ReadNextChar;
    until EOF or not (MRReadChar in CSV_DELIM_CHARSET);

    //#*NOTE: technically can be true if EOF,
    //but if EOF then CurChar is never used 3/13/2014
    vPossDelimChars := False;
  end;

  function SOF: boolean;
  begin
    Result := AStream.Position = 0;
  end;

  function NextChars(ACount: integer): FileString;
  begin
    //#OPTIMIZE: condition
    if ResultCharSize = 1 then
      begin
        SetLength(Result, Min(ACount, vStreamSize{AStream.Size} - AStream.Position));
        AStream.Read(Pointer(Result)^, Length(Result));
        AStream.Seek(-Length(Result), soFromCurrent);
      end else
        begin
          SetLength(Result, Min(ACount, (vStreamSize{AStream.Size} - AStream.Position) div ResultCharSize));
          AStream.Read(Pointer(Result)^, Length(Result) * ResultCharSize);
          AStream.Seek(-Length(Result) * ResultCharSize, soFromCurrent);
        end;
  end;

  procedure GotoNextChars(ACount: integer);
  begin
    //#OPTIMIZE: condition
    if ResultCharSize = 1 then
      AStream.Seek(ACount, soFromCurrent) else
        AStream.Seek(ACount*SizeOf(FileChar), soFromCurrent);
  end;

  procedure GotoPrevChars(ACount: integer);
  begin
    //#OPTIMIZE: condition
    if ResultCharSize = 1 then
      AStream.Seek(-ACount, soFromCurrent) else
        AStream.Seek(-ACount*SizeOf(FileChar), soFromCurrent);
  end;

  procedure GotoPreceedingEOLN(ForItem: boolean = False);
  var
    vOrigPos: integer;

  const
    NMinRowChars = 17;//Length('3-13-13,1,1,1,1,1')

  begin
    //assumes will not hit SOF
    //assumes ending CRLF taken care of by other places
    vOrigPos := AStream.Position;

    vPossDelimChars := True;

    while (NextChars(2) <> #13#10) or (AStream.Position = vOrigPos) do
      if (Length(NextChars(2)) = 2) and (NextChars(2)[2] = #10) and
        (AStream.Position < vOrigPos - SizeOf(FileChar)) then
          begin
            GotoNextChars(1);

            Exit;
          end else
        if (AStream.Position = vOrigPos) and ForItem then
          GotoPrevChars(NMinRowChars) else
            GotoPrevChars(1);
  end;

  var
    CurField: string;
    CurCol: integer;

  procedure InitParsingState;
  begin
    //Initialize Parsing State
    CurCol := -1;
    vPossDelimChars := True;
    SkipExistingDelimChars;
    vStreamSize := AStream.Size;
  end;

  procedure BacktrackTo(APos: integer; ASafeMode: boolean = False);
  begin
    if ASafeMode then
      AStream.Seek(Pred(APos), soFromBeginning) else
        AStream.Seek(APos, soFromBeginning);

    ReadNextChar;
    vPossDelimChars := False;
    CurCol := Ord(High(TFieldType));
  end;

  procedure ReadQuotedText;
  var
    vHadPrevQuoteChar: boolean;
  begin
    vHadPrevQuoteChar := False;
    while MRReadChar = '"' do
      begin
        if vHadPrevQuoteChar then
          CurField := CurField + MRReadChar;
        ReadNextChar;

        while MRReadChar <> '"' do
          begin
            CurField := CurField + MRReadChar;
            ReadNextChar;
          end;

        if EOF then
          break;

        ReadNextChar;
        vHadPrevQuoteChar := True;
      end;
  end;

  procedure GetNextFieldValue;
  begin
    if EOF then Exit;

    CurCol := (CurCol+1) mod Succ(Ord(High(TFieldType)));
    CurField := '';
    if MRReadChar = '"' then
      ReadQuotedText else
        begin
          repeat
            CurField := CurField + MRReadChar;
            if not EOF then
              ReadNextChar;
          until EOF or (MRReadChar in CSV_DELIM_CHARSET);
          if EOF then
            if not (MRReadChar in CSV_DELIM_CHARSET) then
              CurField := CurField + MRReadChar;
        end;
    vPossDelimChars := True;

    SkipExistingDelimChars;
  end;

  var
    ColFieldTypes: array [Ord(Low(TFieldType))..Ord(High(TFieldType))] of TFieldType;

  procedure ResolveCurColFieldType;
  var
    vField: string;
  begin
    vField := LowerCase(CurField);
    if vField = 'date' then
      ColFieldTypes[CurCol] := ftDate else
    if vField = 'open' then
      ColFieldTypes[CurCol] := ftOpen else
    if vField = 'high' then
      ColFieldTypes[CurCol] := ftHigh else
    if vField = 'low' then
      ColFieldTypes[CurCol] := ftLow else
    if vField = 'close' then
      ColFieldTypes[CurCol] := ftClose else
    if vField = 'volume' then
      ColFieldTypes[CurCol] := ftVolume else
    if Pos('close', vField) > 0 then
      ColFieldTypes[CurCol] := ftAdjClose else
        raise EInvalidOperation.Create('Unrecognized file format: unrecognized column name found.');
  end;

  procedure WriteItemAsFieldValue(var AData: TDayIndexData);
  begin
    case ColFieldTypes[CurCol] of
      ftDate:AData.Date := ExStrToDate(CurField);
      ftOpen:AData.Open := StrToFloat(CurField);
      ftHigh:AData.High := StrToFloat(CurField);
      ftLow:AData.Low := StrToFloat(CurField);
      ftClose:AData.Close := StrToFloat(CurField);
      ftVolume:AData.Volume := StrToFloat(CurField);
      ftAdjClose:AData.AdjClose := StrToFloat(CurField);
    end;
  end;

  procedure VerifyFields;
  var
    iField: TFieldType;
    iColumn: integer;

    IsUsedFlags: array [Low(TFieldType)..High(TFieldType)] of boolean;

  begin
    //* Set all to false
    for iField := Low(TFieldType) to High(TFieldType) do
      IsUsedFlags[iField] := False;

    //* set found to true
    for iColumn := Low(ColFieldTypes) to High(ColFieldTypes) do
      IsUsedFlags[ColFieldTypes[iColumn]] := True;

    //* throw error on first one not found
    for iField := Low(TFieldType) to High(TFieldType) do
      if not IsUsedFlags[iField] then
        begin
          raise EInvalidOperation.Create('Bad file format: one or more column names are missing!');
          break;
        end;
  end;

  procedure LoadHeader;
  var
    iField: TFieldType;

  begin
    for iField := Low(TFieldType) to High(TFieldType) do
      begin
        GetNextFieldValue;
        ResolveCurColFieldType;
      end;

    VerifyFields;

    if EOF then
      raise EInvalidOperation.Create('Cannot complete shallow Equity New High Info Retrieval: Not enough Data')
  end;

  procedure LoadRowInto(var ADayData: TDayIndexData);
  var
    iField: TFieldType;
  begin
    for iField := Low(TFieldType) to High(TFieldType) do
      begin
        GetNextFieldValue;
        WriteItemAsFieldValue(ADayData);
      end;
  end;

  var
    OrderReversed: boolean;

    vTopDay,
    vBottomDay,

    vFirstDay,
    vEarlierDay,
    vLastDay: TDayIndexData;

    vBeginDate: TDate;

    vBeforeLastDayPos,
    vFirstDayPos,
    vAfterFirstDayPos: integer;

  function HasUnprocessedDays: boolean;
  begin
    //** use Position of stream because we don't always have the first day in the
    //   file, due to optimization
    Result := (
      ((AStream.Position > vFirstDayPos) and not OrderReversed) or

      (((AStream.Position < AStream.Size - SizeOf(FileChar)*Length(#13#10)) or
        (AStream.Position < AStream.Size - SizeOf(FileChar)*Length(#10)))
       and OrderReversed));
  end;

  function NotYetCoveredTimePeriod: boolean;
  begin
    Result :=
      (ARatePeriod.PeriodStr = AllDataPeriodStr)
      or
      (
        (ARatePeriod.PeriodStr <> AllDataPeriodStr) and
        (vEarlierDay.Date >= vBeginDate)
      );
  end;

  function FoundAllNeededData: boolean;
  begin
    Result := (
      (ARatePeriod.PeriodStr <> AllDataPeriodStr) and
      (vEarlierDay.Date <= vBeginDate)
    ) or
    (ARatePeriod.PeriodStr = AllDataPeriodStr);
  end;

  procedure GotoLastDay;
  begin
    //** Goto End of File
    GotoEOF;

    //** Goto Just before Last Day
    GotoPreceedingEOLN;
    if (AStream.Position = AStream.Size - SizeOf(FileChar)*Length(#13#10)) or
      (AStream.Position = AStream.Size - SizeOf(FileChar)*Length(#10)) then
        GotoPreceedingEOLN;

    SkipExistingDelimChars;
  end;

  procedure DetermineDataOrder;
  begin
    //#ASSUMPTION: assume end day at BOTTOM of file if latest data less than 2 days ago
    //Problem when NDays = 2 ?

    if Trunc(Now) - Trunc(vBottomDay.Date) >= 2 then
      begin
        //** Get Top Day
        BacktrackTo(vFirstDayPos, True);
        LoadRowInto(vTopDay);

        //** Determine what order the data is in
        OrderReversed := vBottomDay.Date < vTopDay.Date;

        if not OrderReversed then
          BacktrackTo(vBeforeLastDayPos, True);

        if OrderReversed then
          vFirstDay := vBottomDay else
            vFirstDay := vTopDay;

        if OrderReversed then
          vLastDay := vTopDay else
            vLastDay := vBottomDay;
      end else
        begin
          OrderReversed := False;

          //vLastDay := vTopDay;
          vLastDay := vBottomDay;
        end;
  end;

  procedure LoadPrevRow;
  var
    vBeforeDayPos: integer;

  begin
    GotoPreceedingEOLN(True);

    vBeforeDayPos := AStream.Position;

    SkipExistingDelimChars;
    LoadRowInto(vEarlierDay);

    AStream.Seek(vBeforeDayPos, soFromBeginning);
  end;

begin
  //* Initialize
  Result.Success := False;
  AStream.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
  InitParsingState;

  //** Load CSV Header
  LoadHeader;
  vFirstDayPos := AStream.Position;

  //** Get Last Day
  GotoLastDay;
  vBeforeLastDayPos := AStream.Position;
  LoadRowInto(vBottomDay);

  //** IF Only 1 Data Day:
  if vFirstDayPos = vBeforeLastDayPos then
    begin
      //return results
      Result.Success := True;
      Result.High := vBottomDay.High;
      Exit;
    end;

  //** Go back to Last Day in File
  BacktrackTo(vBeforeLastDayPos);

  //** Determine what order the data is in
  DetermineDataOrder;

  //** Determine Date to scan back to if opted for
  if ARatePeriod.PeriodStr <> AllDataPeriodStr then
    vBeginDate := MoveDateBack(vLastDay.Date, ARatePeriod.TimePeriod);

  //* Initialize Loop Variables
  Result.High := vLastDay.High;
  vEarlierDay := vLastDay;

  while HasUnProcessedDays and NotYetCoveredTimePeriod do
    begin
      //** Goto Previous Day's Row
      if OrderReversed then
        LoadRowInto(vEarlierDay) else
          LoadPrevRow;

      //** Update High
      if NotYetCoveredTimePeriod then
        Result.High := Max(Result.High, vEarlierDay.High);
    end;

  Result.Success := FoundAllNeededData;
end;

end.
```

An Example CSV is below.  Note that sometimes the CSV line items are found in reverse order in the file (latest date first).

```
Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume,Adj Close
11/3/2014,12,12.06,11.75,11.98,19700,11.98
11/4/2014,12,12,10.62,11.55,39200,11.55
11/5/2014,11.6,11.85,11.6,11.85,3100,11.85
11/6/2014,11.85,11.85,11.85,11.85,0,11.85
11/7/2014,11.5,11.5,10.35,11,35900,11
11/10/2014,11.12,11.12,11.12,11.12,200,11.12
11/11/2014,11.5,11.5,11.5,11.5,200,11.5
11/12/2014,11.75,11.85,11.15,11.45,3500,11.45
11/13/2014,11.45,11.45,11.45,11.45,0,11.45
11/14/2014,11.45,11.45,11.45,11.45,0,11.45
11/17/2014,11.07,11.28,11.07,11.28,1600,11.28
11/18/2014,11.07,11.74,11.06,11.74,8100,11.74
11/19/2014,11.1,11.5,11,11.5,11600,11.5
11/20/2014,11.1,11.5,11.1,11.5,3100,11.5
11/21/2014,11.49,11.5,11.23,11.25,15100,11.25
11/24/2014,11.25,11.35,11.25,11.25,900,11.25
11/25/2014,11.48,11.5,11.25,11.5,355300,11.5
11/26/2014,11.75,11.75,11.5,11.5,261300,11.5
11/28/2014,11.75,11.8,11.75,11.8,16300,11.8
12/1/2014,11.25,11.8,11.02,11.5,23800,11.5
12/2/2014,11.6,11.6,11.47,11.5,57600,11.5
12/3/2014,11.57,11.75,11.41,11.69,240700,11.69
12/4/2014,11.74,11.75,11.49,11.65,41100,11.65
12/5/2014,11.65,11.85,11.56,11.8,267200,11.8
12/8/2014,11.8,11.85,11.68,11.8,168700,11.8
```

Comment: File I/O is more or less a serial process, don't expect parallel gain for that.

Comment: Yes. Disk I/O is surely the bottle neck. Multi-threading is for CPU bound tasks. Before investing development time on optimisations, be sure you are optimising the real bottleneck.

Comment: You also seem to have mixed together multiple different aspects all into one function. That makes it hard to work on your code. You really need to factor the code so that each part deals with one single tasks.

Comment: And if disk access is not the bottleneck then you are surely doing something wrong. Disk access should be much slower than parsing. You should be able to get it all done in a single threaded manner in pretty much the same time as it takes to read from the disk.

Comment: I revised my statement to be more clear about time taken for Disk I/O.  I'll see what I can do about simplifying the code.  Thanks for a quick response.

Comment: I also note that you are trying to use a more scalable memory manager. A far more effective approach is to cut down on the amount of heap allocation that you do. Surely possible. Beneficial for single threaded code too. I still feel that you should be able to code this single threaded near enough as fast as multi threaded

Comment: Thanks for the pointers...we'll see where it goes... P.S. I simplified my code some...

Comment: As others have said, I/O *should be* the bottle-neck. The task you've described *should be* solvable in O(n) time. So the fact that you're seeing a significant improvement in a multi-threaded solution suggests a flaw in your algorithm (As @David says, I wouldn't expect any improvement). I've skimmed through your code and notice you seem to be doing a lot of 'backtracking' through data you've processed before. Basically you're following a naive approach; the ideal approach is to read decent sized **blocks** of data from the stream, when each is done, read the next - and **never** look back!

Comment: I might get a chance to post some more details as an answer this evening. But if someone else wants to elaborate, please go ahead.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to take Intel Threading Building Blocks as memory manager. It scales pretty good up to at least 16 cores (I had  a similar problem here in [Why multithreaded memory allocate/deallocate intensive application does not scale with number of threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912821/why-multithreaded-memory-allocate-deallocate-intensive-application-does-not-scal/26997340#26997340)

In general, even with Intel TBB in main thread execution loop avoid dynamically allocate/deallocate memory. These operations scale always bad.

- Allocate enough memory ( fixed ) for processing before loop starts, and deallocate behind loop end.
- Inside read/processing loop just limit operations to pointer related. Copying memory should be only when necessary.

Input data could be split among different hard disks, even better if they're connected to different controllers. Input data can be memory mapped if you know size in advance, i.e. before processing in thread loop.

Optimize single thread processing as much as possible ( profiling ), then identify parts not scaling with number of threads ( number of threads as parameter ). These parts have to be rewritten. I/o read operations can be cached and/or read data in n * cluster chunks.

These rather general recommendations are based on my experience collected during processing input data of TB size on Windows 7 ( up to 12 ht cores and up to 128 GB RAM ) parallel in threads.